# How to verify digital signatured content and certificate

Tags: javascript, php, html, digital-signature, capicom

I want to verify my base64 encoded string which I got after using capicom js. I found a solution using `CAPICOM_VERIFY_SIGNATURE_ONLY` but it returns as the hash value is not correct. The code I am using is below

```
var verify_fn1   = document.getElementById("sign_verify1"); 
var verify_fn    = SignedData.Verify(szSignature, false, CAPICOM_VERIFY_SIGNATURE_ONLY);
verify_fn1.value = verify_fn;
```